# passing value another activity

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I made a WeatherSyncAdapterClass, I create a method and get the latitude and longitude value from GPS.

```
public void getGPS(){
    Context context = WeatherSyncAdapter.super.getContext();
    gps = new GpsTrack(context);
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        while (lat == 0.0 && lon == 0.0) {
            setLat(gps.getLatitude());
            setLon(gps.getLongitude());
            latitude = Double.toString(lat);
            longitude = Double.toString(lon);
        }
    }
    else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
```

...and then I set the URI value for the "locationsetting" with this statement:

```
    public void setLatLon(double a, double b) {
    //Double.toString(weather.getLatitude()+weather.getLongitude())
    LatLon = Double.toString(a+b);
}
```

(I just set the uri for the location setting from addition latitude and longitude ^_^, I know this is stupid)

My question is how to pass the "LatLon" value to the "mainActivity" for matching the URI? I know intent will pass the value but i think thats will be bad solution cause will (maybe) open the another activity.

please help me :(((

Comment: you want to pass your value from **adapter** to **activity** class?

Comment: use `static` variable.

Comment: have you tried using startActivityForResult in mainActivity class?

Comment: From mainActivity, you want to call another class and get the longitude and latitude values from it, without changing the GUI, right?

Comment: not able to get your point ,what you actually want to do?

Comment: Am I right, Cahyowhy??

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you want to pass value from adapter to Activity? What exactly you want?

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, mainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Lat",Double.toString(a));
intent.putExtra("Lon",Double.toString(b));
startActivity(intent);
```

Using the intents you can pass values to other activities.
`intent.putExtra` method/function will send data in form of key,value pair.

In the `MainActivity.class` you can use following code to retrive the data from intent

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String latitude = intent.getStringExtra("Lat");
String longitude = intent.getStringExtra("Lon");
```

Comment: yes, i wanna passing the value from the syncAdapter to the mainActivity, Intent its doesnt work cause i see "red" on "startActivity", what should i do :(

Comment: you have to get the context reference and then try startActivity. You can use the following code to get the context reference getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent). If this does not help can you place the code so I can fix it.